# RSS memory data in docker stats api for cgroup2

Tags: docker, cgroups, docker-api

In cgroup we get all the docker container memory stats from the below API.

example : curl -X GET "http://172.16.0.1:2375/v1.24/containers/<container_name>/stats?stream=0

```
{'usage': 447074304,
 'max_usage': 460214272,
 'stats': {'active_anon': 129630208,
  'active_file': 130027520,
  'cache': 257986560,
  'dirty': 0,
  'hierarchical_memory_limit': 9223372036854771712,
  'hierarchical_memsw_limit': 9223372036854771712,
  'inactive_anon': 50491392,
  'inactive_file': 127221760,
  'mapped_file': 107593728,
  'pgfault': 992112,
  'pgmajfault': 99,
  'pgpgin': 1029171,
  'pgpgout': 953253,
  'rss': 180805632,
  'rss_huge': 127926272,
  'shmem': 0,
  'swap': 0,
  'total_active_anon': 129630208,
  'total_active_file': 130027520,
  'total_cache': 257986560,
  'total_dirty': 0,
  'total_inactive_anon': 50491392,
  'total_inactive_file': 127221760,
  'total_mapped_file': 107593728,
  'total_pgfault': 992112,
  'total_pgmajfault': 99,
  'total_pgpgin': 1029171,
  'total_pgpgout': 953253,
  'total_rss': 180805632,
  'total_rss_huge': 127926272,
  'total_shmem': 0,
  'total_swap': 0,
  'total_unevictable': 0,
  'total_writeback': 0,
  'unevictable': 0,
  'writeback': 0},
 'failcnt': 0,
 'limit': 83795795968}
```

I am looking for the same info in cgroup2 but I found that cgroup2 does not have all the information regarding the memory

```
{'usage': 609529856,
 'stats': {'active_anon': 102400,
  'active_file': 37502976,
  'anon': 321716224,
  'anon_thp': 77594624,
  'file': 260096000,
  'file_dirty': 0,
  'file_mapped': 107474944,
  'file_writeback': 0,
  'inactive_anon': 329601024,
  'inactive_file': 221347840,
  'kernel_stack': 540672,
  'pgactivate': 7270,
  'pgdeactivate': 0,
  'pgfault': 439225,
  'pglazyfree': 0,
  'pglazyfreed': 0,
  'pgmajfault': 91,
  'pgrefill': 0,
  'pgscan': 0,
  'pgsteal': 0,
  'shmem': 1245184,
  'slab': 18472688,
  'slab_reclaimable': 17250928,
  'slab_unreclaimable': 1221760,
  'sock': 8192,
  'thp_collapse_alloc': 0,
  'thp_fault_alloc': 76,
  'unevictable': 0,
  'workingset_activate': 0,
  'workingset_nodereclaim': 0,
  'workingset_refault': 0},
 'limit': 67113873408}
```

Is there any API present to get all the info coming as part of the default cgroup.